# DateTime parsing issue

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to parse this datetime, but it always return false.

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact("07/01/2007 12:15", "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out met)
```

Comment: What do you mean it does "not work"? What is it supposed to do, and what isn't it doing? You will get answers that correspond to the amount of detail you put in your question (lots of detail - good answers, not much detail - bad answers).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The pattern for month is [capital `MM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
```

`mm` stands for minutes and you've already used it at the end.

Answer (score 7):

**The problem is** that at runtime it finds two components of minutes in the given string as specified by the format for parsing. So you're not able to construct a valid DateTime object from the given input-string with format specified. It finds `07` and `15` both as minutes hence the problem.

When you run the code with `ParseExact` and without TryParse, you'll get following exception.

> System.FormatException: DateTime
>   pattern 'm' appears more than once
>   with different values.

**The Solution**: Note that, `mm` is for minutes, `MM` is for months. In your particular case, you need to tell which part is the month and which one is the minutes. Assuming you need `07` as the month, Here's the corrected version of your code.

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("07/01/2007 12:15", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out met)
```